# How to wait for response from service in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display the items using ng-repeat and when the list is initailly loading , trying to call another service to get the details about the first item.
Here is my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    <div ng-click="setCurrentItem(item,$index)" ng-init="initCurrentItem(item,$index)">
       item.id
    </div>
</div>
```

In controller:

```
function init(){    
  itemService.loadItem();    
}

$scope.itemList = function(){
  return itemService.getItemsList();
}
```

from this service I am getting the following data :

```
itemName:x001,
item.id:10
itemName:x002,
item.id:20,
itemName:x003,
item.id:30.
```

I am calling another service to get itemDetails.

```
$scope.currentItemDetails ={};
$scope.currentItemDetails.id ='';
$scope.initCurrentItem(item.index){
  if(scope.currentItemDetails.id === ''){
   $scope.setCurrentItem(item.index);
  }

}
$scope.setCurrentItem = function(item,index){
    item.index = index;
    itemService.loadItemDetails(item.id).then(function(response){
      if(angular.isDefined(response)){
        $scope.currentItemDetails = response.data;
      }
    });
```

when the list loading initailly  and calling initCurrentItem, the currentItemDetails holding last item (itemName:x003,id:30). ng-repeat is repeat the values without waiting response from the service. How do I wait in the loop until I get response from first item?

Answer (score 2):

Just use the same logic in `init` method as you have in the other example - with `.then(` etc. And assign value to the repeating variable **itemList**. Then table HTML will be refreshed automagically when the data arrives and Promise will be resolved:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList">

function init(){    
  itemService.loadItem().then(function(response){
      if(angular.isDefined(response)){
        $scope.itemList = response.data;
      }
    });   
}
```

**UPD**

try calling initCurrentItem after the data is loaded

```
function init(){    
  itemService.loadItem().then(function(response){
    if(angular.isDefined(response)){
      $scope.itemList = response.data;
//here we iterate received array $scope.itemList and call initCurrentItem on each of them
      $scope.itemList.forEach(function(item, i){
       $scope.initCurrentItem(item, i);
    });
   }
  });   
}
```

Comment: loadItem is working fine. I am trying to wait in the loop until I get the response from laodItemDetails() for the first item.currently I am getting last item details instead of first one.

Comment: what does this even mean - 'am trying to wait in the loop' ? there's no WAIT function in Javascript. Do you mean you need to wait for some other response or action to modify the data or what?

Comment: yes I am trying to get the firstItem details but getting the last item details.it seems before I get the response from service for first item it is checking the conditions init and calling setCurrentItem() for second item and so on, finally getting last item values.

Comment: why would you then call ng-init="initCurrentItem(item,$index)" on each item? there should be a better way to achieve this

Comment: how do I use $q in my service call?

Comment: why just not to call initCurrentItem in the then-callback section? check the updated answer

Comment: yes I added initCurrentItem in init(). it solved  my problem . thank you.

Comment: Great that it helped, man! - then you can mark this answer as a correct one